# Parquet version 2 on Impala

Tags: impala

Is there a way to enable impala tables to read version 2 parquet files?

I get an incompatible version error when trying to this. If I convert the source file to parquet version 1 the table works fine. It seems version 2 files are now created as default so I'm hoping there is some setting/configuration that would allow me to use parquet version 2 files with impala

I am using Impala version 4.2.0